# nginx: why no access log for rediect location

Tags: nginx, logging

My nginx config file goes following:

```
server {        
    location /mysite {
        auth_request /authVerify;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        error_page 401 = /login;
    }

    location /authVerify {
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; HttpOnly";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

log related configs use the default settings.

the `auth_request` configration works. But when I send request to `/mysite`, there is only logging of it in access log, there is no logging of `/authVerify` although it actually proxy through this locatoin. If I send request to `/authVerify` directly, there will be loggings as well.

So in the redirect cases how to produce logs for all the locations the request running through?

**Update**
Based on the comment, I set `log_subrequest` as on in `http` block level. After this change, the logs of internal rediect was produced, but the log of original `mysite` location disappear.

Currently after I send one request to `/mysite`, the log is as following:

[image]

I found the following explanation on nginx doc:

`Requests are logged in the context of a location where processing ends. It may be different from the original location, if an internal redirect happens during request processing.`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Is that because of that? Any more methods to log the request's entire flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried enabling log_subrequest?

```
log_subrequest

Context: http, server, and location

Enables or disables logging of sub-requests triggered by internal redirects or SSI requests.

Syntax: on or off

Default value: off
```

Comment: thank you. `log_subrequest` can make the redirect location logged. But the original location's log will not be output. Please see my update in the post. Need more tune.

Comment: It's because the logs only show up from the end processing context, i.e. last subrequest. You can add some X headers to the subrequest and retrieve it to write down to your logs or use some existing pre-defined variables: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addrhttp://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addr